# Base64 is undefined in "Image Picker library" in React native

Tags: react-native

I have installed the "Image Picker" library in my React native project. This library is working well but in console I receive that {base64: undefined}. i am also sharing the code of the function and also the screenshot of the console.
[

```js
const chooseFile = (type) => {
        let options = {
            mediaType: type,
            maxWidth: 300,
            maxHeight: 550,
            quality: 1,
        };
        launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);
            if (response.didCancel) {
                alert('User cancelled to pick the image');
                return;
            } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
                alert('Camera not available on device');
                return;
            } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
                alert('Permission not satisfied');
                return;
            } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
                alert(response.errorMessage);
                return;
            }
            console.log('base64 => ', response.base64);
            console.log('uri => ', response.uri);
            console.log('width => ', response.width);
            console.log('height => ', response.height);
            console.log('fileSize => ', response.fileSize);
            console.log('type => ', response.type);
            console.log('fileName => ', response.fileName);
            setFilePath(response);
        });
    };
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7x54.png)

Comment: what does this console.log('Response = ', response); log ? can you show the output

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else stuck on this, you need to add `includeBase64` to the options:

```
launchImageLibrary(
  {
    mediaType: 'photo',
    includeBase64: true
  }
```